# iterator vs reverse_iterator

Tags: c++, performance, stl, stdmap

I'm using `std::map` to store a lot of elements (pairs of elements) and I have a "little" doubt.   What is more efficient to iterate all elements over my `std::map`, `iterator` or `reverse_iterator`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Does it really matter?  these are the types of the micro optimizations you must try to avoid IMHO. Also, even if the iteration time changes for very large number of elements in the map, the fact that you are trying to iterate through all the elements of such a big map means that most probably you have chosen a wrong data structure.

Comment: Well, you're right.
I wanted to print all elements with the operator "<<" to my class, but if print all std::map, time consuming is excessive. better not do it.
Thank you

Answer (score 34):

For the record, **dereferencing `reverse_iterator`** on `std::map` and `std::set` containers is **twice as slow** as using `iterator` -- with both -O3 gcc 3.4.6 and MSVC on Intel/AMD processors (almost 3x as slow on PPC architectures.)  Same holds for `const_reverse_iterator` vs. `const_iterator`.  This is due to the fact that `reverse_iterator` *actually* points to the tree node immediately following the tree node to be dereferenced, hence the extra work.  `std::vector` iterators exhibit a much milder difference (`reverse_iterator` is only ~30% slower on PPC, virtually indistinguishable on Intel/AMD.)  Incidentally, a `std::vector` iterator is about 20x faster than a `std::map` or `std::set` iterator.

```
#include <set>
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>
#ifdef _WIN32
#include <sys/timeb.h>
#else
#include <sys/time.h>
#endif
#include <time.h>

#define CONTAINER std::set< int >

double
mygettime(void) {
# ifdef _WIN32
  struct _timeb tb;
  _ftime(&tb);
  return (double)tb.time + (0.001 * (double)tb.millitm);
# else
  struct timeval tv;
  if(gettimeofday(&tv, 0) < 0) {
    perror("oops");
  }
  return (double)tv.tv_sec + (0.000001 * (double)tv.tv_usec);
# endif
}


int main() {
  int i, x = 0;
  CONTAINER bla;
  for (i = 0; i < 10000; bla.insert(bla.end(), i++)) ;

  double t1 = mygettime();

  for (i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
    for (CONTAINER::iterator it = bla.begin(); it != bla.end(); ++it) {
      x ^= *it;
    }
  }

  printf("forward: %f\n", mygettime() - t1);

  double t2 = mygettime();

  for (i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
    for (CONTAINER::reverse_iterator it = bla.rbegin(); it != bla.rend(); ++it) {
      x ^= *it;
    }
  }

  printf("reverse: %f\n", mygettime() - t2);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Up-voted for answering the posed question. Some micro-optimizations are so obvious that not implementing them should be considered bad programming practice/a bug... But I work in a performance critical space; if it were up to me, C++ would be renamed "++C."

Comment: This answer is better than the above one. Why wasn't it chosen to be the correct one? What's more, I am curious about how to implement a reverse iterator in the rb-tree?

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have profiled your code and found there to be a significant difference, I just wouldn't be concerned about it.

> "Premature optimization is the root of
>   all evil."  - Donald Knuth

Answer (score 1):

There will likely be no difference.  std::reverse_iterator is just a template shim that translates ++'s to --'s at compile time.

For a vector or other contiguous storage container, a forward iterator might interact very slightly better with the cache than a reverse iterator would (unlikely you'd be able to detect it), but for a tree-based container it won't make any difference at all--there won't be any locality of reference to exploit.

Comment: Not true, it's not just a template shim.  FYI set/map reverse_iterators are 2x to 3x slower than forward iterators.

Answer (score 0):

Me think it does not make sense to use a reverse_iterator; it's counter intuitive.

It would make the code harder to understand, someone will look at the code and go "wtf"; and if you need to put a comment to explain why, it probably means it's not good code to start with.

Answer (score -1):

I am wondering the need for iteration. Map holds the key-value pairs and normally you use it for the lookup. If you still need to iterate the map for some reasons ( may be deleting pointers contained inside the map etc) then you can use [std::for_each](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/for_each.html). Forget the micro optimizations and you can try to increase the code readability.

Comment: First of all, i did not -1 you, but `std::map` is designed to be iterateable, if you only use key-value pairs, you would probably use a hash map like `std::unordered_map` anyways. Its perfectly fine to use `std::map` if you need key-value AND ordered iteration.