# What is the best way of descending sort?

Tags: c++, sorting, stl

ALL,

std::sort() will sort in ascending order.
Is there an easy, convenient and fast way of doing a descending sort?

Thank you.

Comment: [`std::greater<>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/greater)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9025084/sorting-a-vector-in-descending-order shows you 2 ways

Comment: @user93353, thank you. As I don't use primitives, but a custom made objects I will probably use the second way. (I wish I could accept you answer.)

Answer (score 7):

If you're sorting `int`s, say, in the range `[begin, end)`:

```
std::sort(begin, end, std::greater<int>());
```

[`std::greater`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/greater) is a binary function object that applies `>` to its operands. You could alternatively provide a lambda expression:

```
std::sort(begin, end, [](int a, int b) { return a > b; });
```

Comment: No, I am sorting a custom made object, not a primitive.

Comment: @Igor Then you'll need to pass a function object (perhaps a lambda as above) that takes two `const T&` arguments (where `T` is your type) and returns `true` if the first is less than the second.

Comment: This is what I do: struct Sorter { bool operator()(const CObj &obj1, const CObj &obj2) { return obj1.m_num < obj2.m_num; } } Then somewhere in the code: std::sort( obj1.begin(), obj2.end(), sorter ); I can't use lambda as this will be ported to Mac and it will be compiled under 10.6 which does not support C++11. Any way to modify this? Or I am better off with reverse iterators?

Comment: @Igor: If it makes sense for your objects to be compared with `operator<` you can just implement that operator. (Same with `operator>`, `operator==`, `operator>=` etc.; implement them in terms of each other.) Then `std::greater<CObj>` will just do the right thing.

Answer (score 2):

Write a function to compare:

```
bool comp(int a, int b)
{
    return a > b;
}
```

then to sort, say, a `vector vec`, call `sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), comp)`

Comment: I am sorting a custom made objects and it has a comparator.

Comment: @Igor Does it compare in the way you want? If not, you can always write another one.