# std::sort descending order with operator overloading

Tags: c++, sorting, c++11, std

I have an `std::vector` of object for which I overloaded the `<` operator.

How can I use `std::sort` to sort it in descending order (without needing to write my own Comparator)?

Comment: `std::sort(begin(v), end(v), std::greater<>);`

Comment: `std::sort(v.rbegin(), v.rend());`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sorting a vector in descending order](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9025084/sorting-a-vector-in-descending-order)

Comment: @ GuyGreer Could you explain why you don't need to specify the template argument and leave <> empty?

Comment: As of C++14 there is a specialisation of the comparison functions and that is achieved by passing `void` as the template argument.  At the same time, the standard made `void` the default template parameter if none is specified.  The syntax `std::greater<>` instantiates the object with the default arguments

Comment: @GuyGreer but that object still needs to be instantiated, i.e., `std::greater<>()`

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Yes, I forgot to do that and it's too late to edit it now

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could simply transpose the arguments to `std::less` with the help of `std::bind`:

```
using namespace std::placeholders;
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), std::bind(std::less<T>{}, _2, _1));
```

But I think it'd be much cleaner to simply write the equivalent short lambda, even if it goes against the constraint of not writing your own Comparator:

```
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), [](T const& lhs, T const& rhs) { return rhs < lhs; });
```

Comment: Or even `std::greater<T>`

Comment: @GuyGreer No, not `std::greater<T>`.

Comment: while `std::greater` is not the same as `not2(std::less)`, I'm pretty sure they will give the same result while sorting...

Comment: @GuyGreer `std::greater` uses `operator>`. We don't have that.

Comment: @GuyGreer `std::greater` uses `operator>`, not `operator<`. An answer using that was posted and is deleted already. As for negating with `not_fn`, doesn't that give you `!(a < b)`, which is logically (when all relational operators are overloaded sensibly) `a >= b`, when you need `a > b`?

Comment: Ah, I just assumed that having `operator<` meant having `operator>`.  My bad.

Comment: @hvd Yeah I guess you'd really need a `std::transpose2`... which I don't think exists. The part above the line is probably wrong.

Comment: @Barry Heh, good call, and I think that does exist, though not by that name: `std::bind(std::less<T>(), std::placeholders::_2, std::placeholders::_1)`. The lambda goes against the OP's stated requirement of not creating a custom comparator. `std::bind` doesn't. Yet seeing this mess, I hope the OP has a change of heart and goes for the lambda anyway. :)

Comment: This seems like UB: If you sort `[1, 1]`, both comparisons will produce `true`.

Comment: @KerrekSB Yeah, I've struck it out. Totally wrong. I guess some people would say that having default comparisons would have solved this problem :)

Comment: Can you clarify the benefit of using the lambda vs reverse iterators as suggested in a comment by Piotr Skotnicki?

Comment: @MarkB I think better to just ask Piotr to write an answer instead of always writing comments? I don't like using reverse iterators for anything more complicating than just walking through a container backwards.

Answer (score 3):

```
std::sort(v.rbegin(), v.rend());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sort array by using `std::sort` and then reverse it with `std::reverse`. This will sort in your desired way.

```
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());
std::reverse(v.begin(), v.end());
```