# Sorting vector elements in descending order

Tags: c++

Please tell me what is wrong in my approach.
When I run the code, it is taking too long to compute to see the result.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

vector<int> vec;
vector<int> sort(vector<int> x) {
    vector<int> y;
    int i = 1;
    reset:for(i = 1; i <= x.size(); i++){
        for (int j = 1; j <= x.size();) {
            if (j == i) {
                j++;
            }
            else {
                if (x[i - 1] > x[j - 1]) {
                    j++;
                }
                else {
                    i++;
                    goto reset;
                }
            }
        }
        y.push_back(x[i - 1]);
        x.erase(x.begin() + i - 1);
    }
          return y;
}

int main(){
    vec.push_back(5);
    vec.push_back(9);
    vec.push_back(3);
    vec.push_back(6);
    vec.push_back(2);

    for (int i = 1; i <= vec.size(); i++) {
        cout << sort(vec)[i-1] << " ";
    }
}
```

I am sorting this given sequence of 5 integers into descending order. Please help.

My plan was to search for the greatest integer in the whole vector x and move to it to the vector y and repeat the process.

Comment: You're sorting the vector every time you want to print one element which can't help performance.

Comment: You increment `i`, then call `goto reset;` -> Where's that going to go, and what happens to `i` after the goto?

Comment: If it's taking too long, I assume you mean it never finishes and it's stuck in an infinite loop. Step through in a debugger and you'll see exactly what that loop is doing.

Comment: Please see the edit for understanding what i was trying to do.

Comment: Any reason you're not using `std::sort`?

Comment: @NathanOlive , Actually i didn't know about that function but still i should be able to do sort the vector without the function.

Comment: @AkshitBansal `goto reset;` -- Please, no.  There is no sort routine written for C++, no matter how naive it is, that needs to use this abomination.

Comment: @AkshitBansal *My plan was to search for the greatest integer in the whole vector x and move to it to the vector y and repeat the process.* -- Then learn about what a [heap data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap) is.

If you wanted to do that, *and* you didn't want to use `std::sort`, then the better way to do this is to use a min-heap, not convoluted `goto` loops.

Comment: [Example using heap](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4ccc126fdb074402).  That actually uses a max-heap.  So this is algorithmically how it can be done.  So you can either use the heap functions provided by the standard library, or open up a book on data structures and implement the binary heap yourself.

Answer (score 3):

#### Simple bubble-sort example

I think that your `sort` function is entering an infinite loop because of the `goto reset` statement. If you want to implement a simple bubble-sort algorithm, you can do it like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

void bubble_sort(std::vector<int>& v) {
    if(v.size() == 0) return; 

    for(int max = v.size(); max > 0; max--) {
        for(int i = 1; i < max; i++) {
            int& current = v[i - 1]; 
            int& next = v[i];
            if(current < next) 
                std::swap(current, next); 
        }
    }
}
```

This function takes a vector, and for every consecutive pair of elements in the vector, if they're out of order, it swaps them. This results in the smallest element "bubbling" to the top of the vector. The process is repeated until all the elements are in order.

If we test it, we see that it prints the right answer:

```
int main() {
    std::vector<int> test = {5, 9, 3, 6, 2}; 

    bubble_sort(test);

    for(int i : test) {
        std::cout << i << ' '; 
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

#### Using `std::sort` to do this faster

The standard library provides a `sort` function that'll sort pretty much anything. `std::sort` is really well implemented, it's more efficient than bubble sort, and it's really easy to use.

By default, `std::sort` orders things in ascending order, although it's easy to change it so that it works in descending order. There are two ways to do this. The first way sorts the vector using the reverse iterators (which allow you to pretend the vector is in reverse order), and the second way sorts the vector using `std::greater`, which tells `std::sort` to sort things in reverse order.

```
// Way 1:
std::sort(test.rbegin(), test.rend()); 

// Way 2:
auto compare_func = std::greater<>(); 
std::sort(test.begin(), test.end(), compare_func);
```

We can re-write the program using `std::sort`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> test = {5, 9, 3, 6, 2}; 

    auto compare_function = std::greater<>(); 
    std::sort(test.begin(), test.end(), compare_function); 


    for(int i : test) {
        std::cout << i << ' '; 
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Comment: If you try computing on your own using the code, the goto statement should not lead to an infinite loop. Please explain how an infinite loop is attained.

Comment: You might also mention the most concise solution: `std::sort(test.rbegin(), test.rend())` which requires no function arg.

Comment: There's an infinite loop because every time you jump to `reset`, the values of `i` and `j` are reset to 1, so it starts the loop over. Under certain circumstances, this will result in repeatedly starting over without making any progress while storting.

Answer (score 2):

Why can't you just use std:sort? You can do this:

```
sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [](const int a, const int b) {return a > b; });  //1
```

---

As suggested in the comments, there are two alternatives to the above:

```
std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), std::greater<>());  //2
```

and:

```
std::sort(vec.rbegin(), vec.rend());  //3
```

(2) and (3) avoid a custom comparison function, and (2) is arguably more explicit about it's intent. But I was interested in the performance, and so I did a quick bench comparison of the three.

With Clang 12.0, (1) was fastest:

[image]

Clang results [here](https://quick-bench.com/q/k73eOpmVD0GZ6ElWH0PqXIBFUo4)

However, with GCC 10.3 all three were near identical:

[image]

GCC results [here](https://quick-bench.com/q/89tnchYHi-dwdT3VFdQBY69-pjI)

Interesting results! With GCC, it's your choice as to which version you prefer; otherwise I would go for (1) or (2).

Comment: Using reverse iterators can remove the need for a custom comparison function.

Comment: or `std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), std::greater<>{});`.

Comment: or std::sort(vec.rbegin(), vec.rend());

Comment: @AwesomeJSF See my update above.

Comment: @jignatius Thanks, it's very interesting