# In my program it program the array prints from ascending order, but i'm trying to modify it so it prints in descending order

Tags: c++, arrays, bubble-sort

In my program it program the array prints from ascending order, but i'm trying to modify it so it prints in descending order. Could use some help.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
int main()
{
    const int length = 5;
    int array[length] = {35, 67, 75, 60, 11};

    std::sort(std::begin(array), std::end(array));
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
      std::cout << array[i] << ' ';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9025084/sorting-a-vector-in-descending-order

Answer (score 5):

`std::sort` can take 3rd parameter, a comparator, which will say how to order the elements inside the array.
You can pass one of standard comparators inside your call to `std::sort`

```cpp
std::sort(std::begin(array), std::end(array), std::greater<int>{});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
std::reverse(std::begin(array), std::end(array));
```

---

Another solution using lambda expression

```
std::sort(std::begin(arr),std::end(arr),[](int a, int b) {
    return b < a; 
});
```

Output:

```
75 67 60 35 11
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to go all in on iterators. You already know `std::begin`. Now it is time to meet its mirror-universe double: `std::rbegin`

```
for(auto it = std::rbegin(array); it != std::rend(array); ++it)
{
  std::cout << *it << ' ';
}
```

[Documentation for rbegin](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/rbegin)

[Documentation for rend](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/rend)