# In c++, what is the fastest way to sort in reverse order?

Tags: c++

Is it one of the following or something else?

```
//1
sort(first,last,[](const T &a,const T &b){return comp(b,a);});
//2
sort(first,last,bind(comp,ref(_2),ref(_1));
//3
sort(make_reverse_iterator(last),make_reverse_iterator(first),comp);
//Use value instead of reference if object size is small.
```

This is not a duplicate of [Sorting a vector in descending order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9025084) ,this one considers user-defined comparison function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sorting a vector in descending order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9025084/sorting-a-vector-in-descending-order)

Comment: @smac89 Not exactly. That is for int.

Comment: one idea using a `std::set` and operating on it with reverse iterators

Answer (score 0):

No easier way than to simply reverse your comparator. If your comparator returns `true` when it compares `A` and `B`, make it return `false` instead, and vice versa.

*Make sure to take care of the case where `A` and `B` are equal; that case, you want the comparator to still return `false`*

It doesn't get any faster when you do that btw.

Comment: What will be faster usually, lambda or bind?

Comment: @user I'd say it doesn't matter, but you should probably do a benchmark to test that theory. IMO, use lambda as much as possible (and watch those scopes!)

Comment: @smac89 The comparison function object for `std::sort` returns a `bool`. Returning -1 instead of 1 won't work.

Comment: @Blastfurnace ahh yes thanks. I was thinking java when I wrote that

Comment: The "vice versa" is not quite that simple - your original comparator will also return `false` if `A` and `B` are equivalent, and in that case your new comparator needs to return `false` as well.

Comment: It turns out that lambda is significantly faster

Comment: @user: Are you compiling with optimization fully enabled (e.g. `g++ -O3`)?

Comment: @JohnZwinck I mainly use MSVC with full optimization. Further discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57830971/why-wrapping-a-function-into-a-lambda-potentially-make-the-program-faster

Answer (score -1):

Benchmark shows using a lambda is much faster than the other two.