# Why wrapping a function into a lambda potentially make the program faster?

Tags: c++, performance, lambda, stl, inlining

The title may be too general. I am benchmarking the following 2 statements on a large `vector<unsigned> v`:

```
sort(v.begin(), v.end(), l);

sort(v.begin(), v.end(), [](unsigned a, unsigned b) { return l(a, b); });
```

where `l` is defined as

```
bool l(unsigned a, unsigned b) { return a < b; }
```

The result surprises me: the second is as fast as `sort(v.begin(), v.end());` or `sort(v.begin(), v.end(), std::less<>());` while the first is significantly slower.

My question is why wrapping the function in a lambda speeds up the program.

Moreover, `sort(v.begin(), v.end(), [](unsigned a, unsigned b) { return l(b, a); });` is as fast, too.

Related code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>
#include <random>
#include <functional>
#include <algorithm>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::vector;

bool l(unsigned a, unsigned b) { return a < b; };

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    auto random = std::default_random_engine();
    vector<unsigned> d;
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < 100000000; ++i)
        d.push_back(random());
    auto t0 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::sort(d.begin(), d.end());
    auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    cout << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(t1 - t0).count() << endl;


    d.clear();
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < 100000000; ++i)
        d.push_back(random());
    t0 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::sort(d.begin(), d.end(), l);
    t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    cout << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(t1 - t0).count() << endl;

    d.clear();
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < 100000000; ++i)
        d.push_back(random());
    t0 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::sort(d.begin(), d.end(), [](unsigned a, unsigned b) {return l(a, b); });
    t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    cout << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(t1 - t0).count() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Tested on both g++ and MSVC.

Update:

I found that the lambda version generate exactly same assembly code as default one (`sort(v.begin(), v.end())`), while the one using a function is different. But I do not know assembly and thus can't do more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sort` is potentially a big function, so it's usually not inlined.  Therefore, it is compiled alone.  Consider `sort`:

```
template <typename RanIt, typename Pred>
void sort(RanIt, RanIt, Pred)
{
}
```

If `Pred` is `bool (*)(unsigned, unsigned)`, there is no way to inline the function — a function pointer type cannot uniquely identify a function.  There is only one `sort<It, It, bool (*)(unsigned, unsigned)>`, and it is invoked by all calls with different function pointers.  The user passes `l` to the function, but that's just processed as an ordinary argument.  It is therefore impossible to inline the call.

If `Pred` is a lambda, it is trivial to inline the function call — the lambda type uniquely identifies a function.  Every call to this instantiation of `sort` invoke the same (lambda) function, so we don't have the problem for function pointers.  The lambda itself contains a direct call to `l`, which is also easy to inline.  Therefore, the compiler inlines all function calls and generate the same code as a no-predicate `sort`.

---

The case with a function closure type (`std::less<>`) is similar: the behavior of calling a `std::less<>` is fully known when compiling `sort`, so inlining is trivial.

Comment: Sorry I don't quite understand. What do you mean by "If Pred is a lambda, it is trivial to inline the function call"? Does that mean the comparison is compiled within the function `sort`?

Comment: @user The reason is given after the dash symbol "—": the lambda type uniquely identifies a function.

Comment: @ L. F. Does that mean the comparison is compiled within the function sort?

Comment: @user When the template is instantiated, the compiler obviously is aware of the types used to instantiate it (the lambda type), so yeah, you are right

Comment: But according to the assembly, it's not the case. Thay are:`std::_Sort_unchecked<unsigned int *,std::less<void> > (07FF7873F1D50h)` for the no-pred one, `std::_Sort_unchecked<unsigned int *,bool (__cdecl*)(unsigned int,unsigned int)> (07FF7873F17D0h)` for the function, and `std::_Sort_unchecked<unsigned int *,<lambda_53300caec326e2a90729d913f36311e2> > (07FF7873F1A80h)` for the lambda

Comment: @user Your assembly shows that it is the case :)  Given solely `<lambda_53300caec326e2a90729d913f36311e2>` or `std::less<void>`, the compiler is able to inline the call.  Given `bool (__cdecl*)(unsigned int,unsigned int)`, it can't.

Comment: @F.L.Yes, it seems. There are 10 `call`s in sort function taking a function, 4 in other 2 each.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199103/discussion-between-l-f-and-user).